# Expected Members of a Randomly Selected Subset

Tags: probability, expectation

I have a set $A$ of size $n$, and want to construct a random subset $S \subseteq A$. Each element of $A$ has a probability of being chosen to be in $S$, $\forall_{a \in A} \,\; p_a = Prob(a \in S)$.

**Is there an existing notion for the expected composition of $S$?**

For example, suppose $A = \{0.25, 0.75\}$ (with members labeled by their probability of being chosen). My intuition is that $E[S] = \{0.75\}$. I get this by finding the expected number of elements of $S$, $E[|S|] = 1$, and then guessing that the highest probability member will be the expected choice.

Is there any notion that formalizes something like my intuition?

Thanks for any help,

Federico

Comment: Do you mean "how many elements is $S$ expected to contain"?  By linearity that's just $\sum p_a$.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  If all you are asking is for the expected number of elements in $S$, that is $\sum p_a$ as I said.  I don't know what it means to ask for the "expected contents".  If $A=\{0,1\}$ has two elements each with a probability $\frac 12$ of being in $S$ then the expected size of $S$ is $1$...what would you want to say the "expected contents" are?

Comment: That is a good point. In the event of a tie I would accept either answer S={0} or S={1}.

Comment: But if the probabilities were $\frac 12 - 10^{-10000},\frac 12 +10^{-10000}$ you would require the answer $S=\{1\}$?  Seems like a very unstable notion.  What if the probabilities were $.1,.1$?  Then the expected size is $.2$ ...  What are the expected contents?

Comment: I don't want to define my own function, and so don't require anything from the results. I'm looking for existing work on expected result of random choices of subsets. In the former case S = {1} is consistent with my intuition. In the latter case I would imagine the set S would be empty.

Comment: There is no notion I am aware of concerning expected sets, so you'll need to define what you mean by that if you expect an answer.  In truth I don't think there's likely to be a useful concept that does anything like what you want, but of course I may be wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Another way to put it is, if I have n unique coins, each with its own probability of landing heads, what is the expected combination of coins that land heads after all of them are flipped once? Maybe it's a fuzzy set where each coins membership is the probability of landing heads?

Comment: Well, if you don't mind fuzzy sets then you can just take the set $\{p_a\}$.  That is, each element is reflected in the "expected set" with precisely the given probability.  That notion makes sense, though I don't think it adds much to the definition of the set up.

Comment: Are you literally asking what is the most likely subset to appear? The "mode" of the probability distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's really a definitive answer to your question, as others have stated in the comments. However, what you are talking about may be related to the notion of Maximum Likelihood Estimators in the context of classification (and other applied statistical fields including machine learning). Of course here we are not figuring the most likely parameters, but rather the most likely set. This is a technique used commonly in Naive Bayes, and the like, because we figure out the most likely label a certain instance of data may have.

There is no conventionally defined "expected value" function on such a process, because expected value of a random variable specifically refers to random variables that are $\Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ (conventionally, of course. There will be variants). However, if your resultant of the process is a set, naturally there is no conventional notion of how to multiply sets by a probability, or add them like in the expected value function we are familiar with.

Back to my point on MLE; you may be trying to find out a "most likely set", if you will. In applications such as machine learning, you have some probabilities and are trying to figure out the most likely labels for a certain collection of data. Of course, depending on the application there are numerous ways of doing this. For more on MLE, there's always the wikipedia course, or several edX resources available online.

For example, you can select an element to be in the set (assuming all their probabilities are independent) if it has greater than 0.5 probability, or rather select the expected value of elements with greatest probability to be in the set (see comments).

Hope this helps you gain some kind of idea as to what your idea means. Not really a math thing, just a kind of design thing (as these sets usually have meaning).